# I need to trace the edge of a hexagon point by point

Tags: trigonometry, geometry

To create an animation in code I first need to be able to describe a point by point path around a hexagonal shape. I already have the $\displaystyle \frac{x}{y}$ coordinate of each vertex. I don't know which direction I will be travelling around the edge so any solution should be able to work in either direction.

The radius, and therefore each side, of the hexagon is 20 pixels. I need to produce a set of $20$ points for each side that maps the $x$ and $y$ position of each point in that path. This is obviously easy for straight lines where each point increments $1$ for each step and the other axis remains static. With the angled sides I am failing get the trigonometry required to plot the points.

I'm fairly positive this is trivial but would appreciate some help getting clear in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an ordered list of vertices, pick a vertex $(x_1,y_1)$ that you want to start at and then pick the next vertex in the list $(x_2,y_2)$. From there you have two vertices which gives you the basis for the parametric equation of a line.

$x = (1 - t) x_1 + t x_2$

$y = (1 - t) y_1 + t y_2$

Iterate over values of $t \in [0,1]$ and place a pixel at the deduced $(x,y)$ coordinate. Then start the process over again with the second vertex as the first and the next vertex in line as the second. Continue the process until you return to the original vertex.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting answer. Would you mind explaining the algebra please?

Comment: @voncox, the parametric line segment is a weighted sum of the two vertices. When $t$ is zero you are initially at vertex $(x_1, y_1)$, and as $t$ increases to $t = 0.5$, you are at the mid-point and at $t = 1$ you arrive at vertex $(x_2, y_2)$. I suggest you draw a figure to better see the intuition.

Comment: Is it correct to say that t = the number of iterations I need to perform along the line segment. For each iteration xPixel = (1-t)*x1+t*x2 and yPixel = (1-t)*y1+t*y2 ?

Comment: @voncox, If you want to create $n \ge 1$ number of intermediate points (i.e., number of iterations), your step size $\Delta t = 1 / n$ for $t = 0$ $t \le 1$, $t \leftarrow t + \Delta t$.

Comment: I think what you're saying (probably very clearly) is that if I have a known finite number of iterations then each iteration should increment t by a value of t/number of iterations.

Comment: @voncox, Correct. And if you are concerned the resolution mismatch between client and screen space, you can write your code to make line segments between $t$ and $t + \Delta t$ to smooth things out.